# DDOS protection from ISP side, UDP protocol, whitelist

Tags: ddos, udp

Is it possible to ignore packets from ISP side which are incoming to my server?

Is possible this kind of situation ? :

I have white list of IP addresses.
I continually update white list and sends it to ISP(?).
ISP checks if UDP packet sender's ip address is on white list. If it is - ISP sends packet to my server. If it isn't, it blocks it so my bandwidth is not wasted.

Thanks for replies.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking the wrong people. If you want to know if party A will do something for you, don't ask party B; ask party A!

Answer (score 1):

Ask your Internet Service Provider to find out if your Internet Service Provider can provide this service for you. We cannot answer this any other way.

If you want to do it on your side, any decent firewall can do it, but your bandwidth will still be wasted.

Answer (score 0):

If I was your ISP and you had servers my answer would be no.

1. If you install servers at the end of an link I'm providing you, I expect you will install and manage your own security devices.
2. As an ISP, I would want my customer to be setup the same across my network...unless you pay me accordingly. Especially if it's to consume less bandwidth...that I make profit with by charging it to you.
3. Before option 2, I would offer you to host and manage your system, for a little less then option 2.

So the answer is yes, it is technically possible. But don't expect a positive answer form your ISP unless they offer managed services.

Comment: -1...please explain why, the person asks if it's technically possible...and it is.